# Sorting by substraction or compare returns different values

Tags: javascript

I have tackled a weird issue, handling with sorting long numeric strings.
If the sort function is:

```
(a,b) => b > a
```

The sort is wrong.
Although if the sort function is:

```
(a,b) => b - a
```

The sort is correct.

How is it possible?

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/dh1j867f/

Comment: I was going to say the same as Dummy, but when I tried your fiddle in Firefox, both options actually worked equally well. But only the subtraction method makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the `Array.prototype.sort()` function expects the function argument you pass to it to return a number. If this number is **negative**, a is smaller than b, thus a comes before b, if it is **0**, a is equal to b, else a is greater than b which means a will be placed after b. Your `(a,b) => b > a` is not correct, it returns a `boolean` instead of a `number`. One caveat you need to watch out for when sorting using subtraction like that is overflowing which will give you an unexpected result

Comment: Amazingly simple, quick answer. Thank you!