# typescript how array sorting works

Tags: arrays, sorting, typescript

I want to sort array of objects.I have dates in my object I want to sort the date of objects

```
 sortFunction(data: Array<any>, propertyRetriever: Function, direction : number) {
    data.sort((a, b) => {
        console.log('a : ' + a.id);
        console.log('b : ' + b.id);
        a = propertyRetriever(a);
        b = propertyRetriever(b);
        // We handle undefined value as they are lower than everything else.
        // ex : undefined < 'hello'
       if ((!a && !b) || a === b ) {
             return 0;
       }
       else if (!a) {
           return -1 * direction;
       }
       else if (!b) {
           return 1 * direction;
       }
       else if (a > b) {
            return 1 * direction;
       } else {
            return -1 * direction;
       }
    });
```

propertyRetriever is a function given at call sortFunction

```
   this._sorter.sortFunction(
        myArray,
        t => t[this.sortField],
        this.sortDirection);
  }
```

I call twice this sortFunction with identical array  and I have diffrents results. 
I do not understand why

One would say that he makes his comparisons randomly.

I thought it would start comparing the 1st with the 2nd, ..... but no, if I put a breakpoint on line "a = propertyRetriever(a)"  at the first iteration and I display a and b, they are different to each execution

exemple 
i Have array of obj

```
obj1 = 
    id: 1
    creationDate : Mon Jan 30 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)
    name :albert
obj2 = 
    id: 2
    creationDate : Mon Jan 23 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)
    name :jules
obj3 = 
    id: 3
    creationDate : Mon Jan 05 2016 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)
    name :jules   
.....
obj2000 = 
    id: 2000
    creationDate : Mon Apr 04 2016 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)
    name :jules
```

when sort is executed first time : at console

```
    a: 10
    b: 12
    a: 11
    b: 45
```

at second time

```
    a: 21
    b: 14
    a: 10
    b: 13
```

Comment: Check out this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41611283/sorting-by-substraction-or-compare-returns-different-values/41611449#41611449](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41611283/sorting-by-substraction-or-compare-returns-different-values/41611449#41611449)

Comment: In this question ,boolean  is returned instead of number. In my case, I return a number

Comment: Did you look at my answer to that question?

Comment: Include sample data in question, and the desired outcome of the sorting.